# HTML comments causing an issue exporting CSS files with Grunt-usemin

Tags: html, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I'm using yeoman/grunt to for my build process and I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to build two .css files, one for IE8 and one for everything else. If I place the IE conditional on the outside of the build block, an error is thrown because of the comment within a comment. If I put the IE conditional on the inside it gets stripped out.

```
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main-old-ie.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main-old-ie.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Is there another/better/easier way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of grunt-usemin are you using?

Comment: 0.1.12. Does 2.0 address this?

Comment: Yes it does. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to v2.0. For that functionality.

Comment: thanks. looks like 2.0 was out before I asked this question, should've checked that first.

Comment: Running 2.0.2 and this still fails as `<!-->` is stripped out and is required for non ie browsers - otherwise no styles are loaded.

Comment: @nav I see you commented on https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/263 - Do you have multiple conditionals in the block?

Comment: @Scottux nope just `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->`